# Creating variables dynamically (the same and different ones)

Tags: c++, mql5, mql

I have to listen for changes in many timeseries, so I end up with much boilerplate code like this:

```
/* ------------- 1 -------------- */
int a = my_random_nr();
static int a_last;
if(a != a_last) {/*do something*/};
a_last = a;
/* ------------- 2 -------------- */
double b = my_random_nr();
static double b_last;
if(b != b_last) { /*do something*/ };
b_last = b;
/* ------------- 3 -------------- */
string c = my_random_nr();
static string c_last;
if(c != c_last) { /*do something*/ };
c_last = c;
```

I can also not just write a function for this purpose and reuse it, since its `static <datatype> last` variable would be shared across all function instances, thus interfering with one another.

This would be no problem if there was a way to create that static variable dynamically per function instance, which by default is not possible in C++ (and thus also not in its derived language [MQL5](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/namedconstants/compilemacros)). Yet I found a possibility to do exactly so via the C++ `##` preprocessing operator [as nicely explained here](https://aticleworld.com/token-pasting-operator/).

So in order to do the above with one single line of code, respectively...

```
if( isNew<int>(my_random_nr) ) { /*do something*/ };
```

...I came up with this code:

```
/* --------------- (1/2) ## preprocessing operator ---------------- */

#define UniqueVar(nr) last##nr                             

/* -------------- (2/2) The 'normal' function itself --------------- */

template <typename T>                                  // #define UniqueVar(nr) last##nr →     // #define UniqueVar(nr) last##nr →
bool isNew(T var)                                      // SHOULD (e.g. 1st function instance): // IS (e.g. 1st function instance):
{                
   static T UniqueVar(__COUNTER__);                    // last0                                // last0
   bool is_new;              
   if(var != UniqueVar(__COUNTER__)) is_new = true;    // last0                                // last1
   else                              is_new = false;              
   UniqueVar(__COUNTER__) = var;                       // last0                                // last2
   
   return                            is_new; 
};
```

Unfortunately, however, instead of consistently creating the same varibale `last0` for the 1st function call (please compare with the '***SHOULD***' column in the above code), it generates the different variables `last0`, `last1` and `last2` (see column "***IS***" above).

I tried to remedy this situation by assigning `int unique_ID = __COUNTER__` once at the beginning the `bool isNew(T var)` function and then using this `unique_ID` instead of [**COUNTER**](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/namedconstants/compilemacros#:%7E:text=Compiler%20build%20number-,__COUNTER__,-The%20compiler%20for) each time, but that then dynamically created always the same variable `lastunique_ID`, across all function calls / all function instances, rendering this approach useless.

Does anybody have an idea how to dynamically create always the ***same*** varibale (i.e. `last0`) for the ***same*** function instance, and `last1`, `last2` etc. only for *other* function instances?

Comment: Hm. I think I stick with index funds.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - you're asking about your attempted _solutions_, rather than your problem.  When should a variable be reused (only on different types, or on different callsites)? You might be best served with a generated "token" of sorts denoting which caller is invoking the function.

Comment: *I have to listen for changes in many timeseries, so I end up with much boilerplate code like this:* -- As mentioned previously, it looks like you came up with a "solution", and went down a rabbit hole with it and now want your solution to work.  Take a step back and describe the *high-level* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You understand what I want to achieve: one line of code per timeseries-check. Please feel free to answer with any solution that comes to your mind.

Comment: `std::variant<int, double, std::string> last;` -- Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: "one line of code per timeseries-check" `timeseries_check<int>(); timeseries_check<double>(); timeseries_check<string>();` Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you please elaboarte a bit further how that would help me in the explained context?

Comment: The variant `last` variable can contain 3 different types simultaneously -- you don't need 3 separate variables to manage.  It is equivalent to the `C` `union`, but typesafe and more powerful.  The only thing you need to manage is to get the correct type you are looking for.  But this to me gets over the issue of having to declare different types and managing them by playing naming tricks with macros.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
template<int id, typename T>
struct IsNew
{
    static T last;

    static bool check(T var)
    {
        bool is_new;
        is_new = var != last;
        last = var;
        return is_new;
    }
};
template<int id, typename T>
T IsNew<id, T>::last;
```

It basically does the same thing as the function you've written but it avoids the problem with the `__COUNTER__`.

To test it I wrote this:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int val = rand() % 3;
        if (IsNew<__COUNTER__,int>::check(val))
        {
            std::cout << "[IsNew 1] " <<  "i: "<< i << ", val: " << val << " is new" << std::endl;
        };

        val = rand() % 3;
        if (IsNew<__COUNTER__,int>::check(val))
        {
            std::cout << "[IsNew 2] " << "i: "<< i << ", val: " << val << " is new" << std::endl;
        };
    }
}
```

This example checks if the two instances are independent and produces the following output

```
[IsNew 1] i: 0, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 0, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 1, val: 0 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 1] i: 2, val: 2 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 1] i: 3, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 3, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 4, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 4, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 5, val: 2 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 1] i: 8, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 8, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 9, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 9, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 10, val: 2 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 10, val: 2 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 11, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 11, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 12, val: 2 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 12, val: 2 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 2] i: 13, val: 1 is new // no print for [IsNew 1]
[IsNew 1] i: 14, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 15, val: 2 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 15, val: 0 is new
[IsNew 1] i: 16, val: 0 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 1] i: 17, val: 2 is new // no print for [IsNew 2]
[IsNew 1] i: 18, val: 1 is new
[IsNew 2] i: 18, val: 1 is new
```

This works because a new data type gets instantiated for each value of `id`.

Comment: If I could pass class ... __COUNTER__, then this would theoretically be the solution, yes. Unfortunately, however, [MQL5 is slightly short of supporting this class template syntax](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis/oop/class_templates#MozgiApp-research-topbar-accountManage-button), it throws the ''class' - unexpected token'-error, unfortunately. Thanks for sharing, though! And if two people upvote my question then I will have the "power" to upvote your answer for your effort :-)

Comment: I'll edit the code in the question to fit with `__COUNTER__`, you'd have to check if it works in MQL5, because unfortunately I've no idea how it works or what it is.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try your new code then. But maybe click my above link (in the comment) first and there have a brief look at the section _Class templates_ to avoid potentially unnecessary work.

Comment: All ready the new code in the answer the docs don't mention it so there's a good chance that it won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately it gives me the _'int' - unexpected token_ error — probably a slight syntax discrepancy between both languages. I'll try to rewrite it, but maybe a random number at compile time that can be kept constant at will with _ _ COUNTER _ _ as the random seed and that also works with MQL5 would be more promising?

Comment: Well you could try the code from the previous answer and replace class with typename in the template. You could then use `class UniqueVar(__COUNTER__)` as the name parameter and would be good to go.